# Stored Procedure Archiving data, 16, 1?

Tags: sql

I have this bit of code I'm trying to understand:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ArchiveData
(
@CutOffDate datetime = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF @CutOffDate IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @CutOffDate = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @CutOffDate > DATEADD(mm, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Cannot delete orders from last three months', 16, 1)
        RETURN -1
    END
END

BEGIN TRAN

    INSERT INTO Archive.dbo.Orders
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Orders
    WHERE OrderDate < @CutOffDate

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR ('Error occured while copying data to Archive.dbo.Orders', 16, 1)
        RETURN -1
    END

    INSERT INTO Archive.dbo.OrderDetails
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.OrderDetails
    WHERE OrderID IN
    (
        SELECT OrderID
        FROM dbo.Orders
        WHERE OrderDate < @CutOffDate
    )

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR ('Error occured while copying data to Archive.dbo.OrderDetails', 16, 1)
        RETURN -1
    END

    DELETE dbo.OrderDetails
    WHERE OrderID IN
    (
        SELECT OrderID
        FROM dbo.Orders
        WHERE OrderDate < @CutOffDate
    )

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR ('Error occured while deleting data from     dbo.OrderDetails', 16, 1)
        RETURN -1
    END

    DELETE dbo.Orders
    WHERE OrderDate < @CutOffDate

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR ('Error occured while deleting data from dbo.Orders', 16,     1)
        RETURN -1
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRAN
    RETURN 0
END

END
```

Was just wondering the 16 and o1, seen here: `Error occured while deleting data from     dbo.OrderDetails', 16, 1)`, is that for reporting the error to the log, and 16 is severity, 1 is status? And if so exactly what doe they mean?

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=sql.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the second parameter (16) is the severity.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx):

> Is the user-defined severity level associated with this message. ... Severity levels from 0 through 18 can be specified by any user.

The third parameter (1) is the state.

> If the same user-defined error is raised at multiple locations, using a unique state number for each location can help find which section of code is raising the errors.